# Modification of a file using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, xml-parsing

I have an xml file that looks like

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <product = "AAA">
     <shell name = "110">
         <style = "000" size ="3"/>
         <style = "200" size ="3"/>
         <style = "800" size ="1"/>
         <style = "0900" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
     </product>
     <product = "AAA">
     <shell name = "310">
         <style = "000" size ="3"/>
         <style = "200" size ="3"/>
         <style = "800" size ="1"/>
         <style = "0900" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
     </product>
     <product = "BBB">
     <shell name = "10">
         <style = "000" size ="3"/>
         <style = "200" size ="3"/>
         <style = "800" size ="1"/>
         <style = "0900" size ="3"/>

     </shell name>
     </product>
     <product = "BBB">
      <shell name = "10010">
         <style = "0300" size ="3"/>
         <style = "2030" size ="3"/>
         <style = "8003" size ="1"/>
         <style = "09003" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
     </product>
     <product = "BBB">
      <shell name = "110">
         <style = "0300" size ="3"/>
         <style = "2030" size ="3"/>
         <style = "8003" size ="1"/>
         <style = "09003" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
     </product>
```

I want to write a script that should club the shell of the same product so that I have an output like

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <product = AAA>
     <shell name = "110">
         <style = "000" size ="3"/>
         <style = "200" size ="3"/>
         <style = "800" size ="1"/>
         <style = "0900" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
    <shell name = "310">
         <style = "000" size ="3"/>
         <style = "200" size ="3"/>
         <style = "800" size ="1"/>
         <style = "0900" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
   </product>
     <product = BBB>
    <shell name = "10">
         <style = "000" size ="3"/>
         <style = "200" size ="3"/>
         <style = "800" size ="1"/>
         <style = "0900" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
     <shell name = "10010">
         <style = "0300" size ="3"/>
         <style = "2030" size ="3"/>
         <style = "8003" size ="1"/>
         <style = "09003" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
     <shell name = "110">
         <style = "0300" size ="3"/>
         <style = "2030" size ="3"/>
         <style = "8003" size ="1"/>
         <style = "09003" size ="3"/>
     </shell name>
     </product>
```

Any ideas of how I can proceed??? I was thinking of searching a string </product>

```
 <product = "AAA">
```

but how can I reach to the second occurrence. I know how to read the file and count the number of occurrence of a particular string but can any one help how can I reach the second occurrence of a  particular string?

Comment: Note that your file is not well-formed XML (e.g. "name" attribute for closing tag, "product = BBB" tag).

Comment: use XPath. For example, try entering ``count(//grandchild)`` here: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Comment: here's a chapter about Perl and XML and XPath: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/pxml/ch08_02.htm

Comment: here's another relevant link: http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html

Comment: JohnB: I was just try to explain my problem. I have a well form xml. Can you help?

Comment: I dont knw much about Xpath is there not an easier way to do this?

Comment: please when asking for help take the time to submit well-formed XML, you make everybody who wants to answer waste time fixing it, possibly in ways that do not reflect the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your XML file to be well formed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
     <product id="AAA">
     <shell name="110">
         <style n="000" size="3"/>
         <style n="200" size="3"/>
         <style n="800" size="1"/>
         <style n="0900" size="3"/>
     </shell>
     </product>
     <product id="AAA">
     <shell name="310">
         <style n="000" size="3"/>
         <style n="200" size="3"/>
         <style n="800" size="1"/>
         <style n="0900" size="3"/>
     </shell>
     </product>
     <product id="BBB">
     <shell name="10">
         <style n="000" size="3"/>
         <style n="200" size="3"/>
         <style n="800" size="1"/>
         <style n="0900" size="3"/>

     </shell>
     </product>
     <product id="BBB">
      <shell name="10010">
         <style n="0300" size="3"/>
         <style n="2030" size="3"/>
         <style n="8003" size="1"/>
         <style n="09003" size="3"/>
     </shell>
     </product>
     <product id="BBB">
      <shell name="110">
         <style n="0300" size="3"/>
         <style n="2030" size="3"/>
         <style n="8003" size="1"/>
         <style n="09003" size="3"/>
     </shell>
     </product>
</products>
```

Then I processed it using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open 1.xml ;
for //product {
    my $id = @id ;
    mv shell append //product[@id=$id][1] ;
}
rm //product[not(shell)] ;
save --backup ;
```

Comment: i cant use xml::xsh2, cant we do it without that??

Comment: What can you use? XML::LibXML at least?

Answer (score 1):

With XML::Twig you can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { product => \&product },
                pretty_print => 'indented',
              )
         ->parsefile_inplace( 'so_conc.xml');

sub product
  { my( $t, $product)= @_;
    my $prev_product=  $product->prev_sibling( 'product') || return;
    if( $product->id eq $prev_product->id)
      { $product->first_child( 'shell')->move( last_child => $prev_product);
        $product->delete;
      }
    else
      { $t->flush_up_to( $prev_product); }
  }
```

The `flush_up_to` line is there to ensure that only one product is kept in memory at once, and, coupled with the call to `parsefile_inplace`, updates the original file.